# Are there any big changes to Ba Sing Se since the 100 year war ended?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

In Legend of Korra, it seems that Ba Sing Se hasn't changed much since the 100 year war ended besides that there is still the poor who live in the lower rings and the most important and richest of Ba Sing Se live in the upper rings close to the royal palace.

Not to mention a greedy queen that does not care in the least about her own people, the government or anything else. Not that Ba Sing Se is all bad. I mean at least the Dai Li are better and are loyal to the current ruler.

So my question is, was there any other big changes or changes that occurred in Ba Sing Se (Good and Bad) since the 100 year war ended and the Republic of Nations formed?

Answer (score 6):

Bah. The loyalty of the Dai Li. That seemed to be forced, as after the queen's death we do not see any Dai Li moving to restore order, and at least one joins in the looting directly.

The earth queen was apparently very unpopular with the people (as evidenced by their response to her death), though we cannot say for certain if this is unique to her or if other leaders were equally unpopular. Even when the city was invaded by Fire Nation soldiers, there was no rebellion nor mass looting. While it could be argued that the people then never had a chance, that goes to highlight the difference in the Dai Li. Back then they held the city, while the more recent Dai Li are weak in leadership and unable to maintain order.

There is no brainwashing in new Ba Sing Se. Despite the queen's ruthlessness, she appears to only enslave the air benders within her borders- everyone else has more freedom, if still heavily limited by their money (or lack thereof).

Mako, a firebender, is unmolested in the city, both by the rich but also the poor. This in stark contrast to during the war, when any firebender would surely have been arrested. It would seem the city doesn't hold any grudges and is open to firebenders, making it reasonable to assume other firebenders live in the city at all social levels.

Comment: The Earth Queen was not entirely unpopular. For example Mako & Bolin's grandma adores her. I thought that was a good touch by the way, showing public opinion as being varied.